# Gnome desktop environment: how to get it working on OpenBSD?

Tags: gnome, desktop, openbsd

I have OpenBSD 5.7-amd64 installed and patched with all the latest available fixes.

I would like to have a minimal Gnome desktop environment and I did the following to my user account (not root account):

```
sudo pkg_add -vi gnome-session nautilus gnome-terminal gnome-menus gnome-system-monitor
```

After installation of the above packages, I

```
sudo nano /etc/rc.conf.local
```

and modified/added the following:

```
xdm_flags=NO
gnome_enable=YES
gdm_enable=YES
```

I rebooted my box and logged in to my user account.

After logging in, I am still presented with OpenBSD's default Fvwm manager, Xterm, etc.

Before making this post I had consulted the following tutorials and discovered the instructions they contained to be unworkable.

"Building an OpenBSD desktop"

http://www.bsdnow.tv/tutorials/the-desktop-obsd

"Display Manager on OpenBSD 4.7"

http://www.gabsoftware.com/tips/installing-gnome-desktop-and-gnome-display-manager-on-openbsd-4-7/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ideally, you should install the `gnome` meta-package to ensure that you have all of the required packages installed, particularly DBus - I'd *highly* recommend you do that.

Once you've installed the `gnome` meta package, follow the post-installation instructions in `/usr/local/share/doc/pkg-readme` for the GNOME version you installed (check the file `gnome-{version}` where `{version}` is the GNOME version).

At a high level you need to do the following post-installation steps (all detailed in the aforementioned instructions):

1. Add `dbus_daemon` to `pkg_scripts` in `/etc/rc.conf.local` and start `dbus_daemon`
2. Configure GDM (which it appears you've done)
3. (Optionally) Install `avahi_daemon` and enable multicast by adding `multicast_host=YES` to `/etc/rc.conf.local`.

If you enable multicast, either restart networking (using `/etc/netstart`) or reboot your machine. When you login again (via GDM), you should be using a GNOME desktop.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. I don't wish to install the `gnome` meta-package because it will install lots of applications that I have no use for, eg. zenity, zeitgeist, pulseaudio, multimedia, brassero. I know for a fact that in Debian, the `gnome-core` package will only install the most basic Gnome applications.

Comment: @virvegto Fair enough. If you want to pick n' choose packages, I'd take the `gnome` package dependencies as a starting point. Perhaps download the package file, extract it manually and then check the `+CONTENTS` file to see what else you've missed. It may well just be that you've missed the post-installation steps, so check the package readme too.

Comment: You know what? I installed the `gnome` meta-package and only after the installation was I able to read the relevant *pkg-readmes*. According to the `gnome` pkg-readme, there ARE two choices available to users to install: `gnome` or `gnome-extras`. The `gnome` meta-package only installs the *standard* applications. (The *pkg-readme* didn't elaborate the meaning of `standard`.) The `gnome-extras` installs the complete suite of Gnome applications.

Comment: Well, after installing the `gnome` meta-package, I discovered that it installed far fewer applications on OpenBSD compared to the `gnome-core` meta-package on Debian Wheezy (7) or Jessie (8). [After all, I wish to install only the barest minimum of Gnome.] I'm pleased with what Gnome developers have done for OpenBSD. If you're one of them, kudos to you.

Answer (score 1):

As root, execute these following 4 commands into the terminal...

```
pkg_add gnome
rcctl disable xenodm
rcctl enable multicast messagebus avahi_daemon gdm
reboot
```

done...

(`pkg_add gnome` will take some time, it has many dependencies.)

Comment: worth noting that these instructions may become outdated with time. you can find the most up-to-date instructions at the pkg readme path printed at the end of the `pkg_add gnome` call.